# What tensor rank is a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, tensors

I have heard before a complex number is a scalar, but how does this jive with it's geometric representation which is like a vector? Vectors transform as rank 1 tensors while scalars are rank 0. So which one would the complex number transform as?

Comment: as an element of a vector space it is a rank-one tensor